# require is not define, having this issue while using GSAP in Drupal project

Tags: import, drupal, gsap

I'm new to drupal and as well as in GSAP, I'm using GSAP in my project where i have import GSAP

import { gsap } from 'gsap';

But in console i'm getting says Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Within Drupal, you can have modules you can install within the GUI or using composer package manager.

One module I believe you may be able to use is: https://www.drupal.org/project/gsap